# Web legal compliance

Tags: cookies, privacy, policy

I have a website where I don't ask to user any data, I don't create cookies and I have only AWStats available in the cPanel (preinstalled by the hosting mantainer).

Do I still need to show any legal information (i.e. GDPR, privacy policy, cookie policy) or can I omit all things?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make any mention of GDPR - that's just one of the applicable laws.

If you don't set any persistent third-party cookies and do not use any third party scripts that set third party cookies (like Google Analytics or Facebook buttons), you don't need a cookie pop-up.

Strictly speaking, your web logs may contain personal data in the form of IP addresses and user agent strings. That data can be reasonably kept for a short period, say 10-30 days, for the purposes of combating abuse, but after that you should either truncate logs or strip out data that can be associated with any individual - and this should be mentioned in your privacy policy too. AWStats typically generates aggregate info from raw logs, and that's fine, so long as it does not end up containing data that allows you to identify individuals (for example, don't store GeoIP data at resolution finer than a city).

You should still have a privacy policy - a policy is just that, it's not something visitors need to agree to, it just tells them how you handle their data. If you don't collect data, don't set cookies, don't share with any third parties, then that's what it needs to say. You don't need a separate cookie policy, especially if you're not using them beyond what's "strictly necessary".

Make sure you have set all applicable [HTTP security headers](https://securityheaders.com), and (if you're not already) you should be using HTTPS, even for a static site.

Run your site through [Webbkoll](https://webbkoll.dataskydd.net/en/) and [Cookiebot](https://www.cookiebot.com/en/) to check how the outside world sees it.